# object:scaling is not working with bounding object

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am new in Fabric js. can anyone suggest me for restrict scale object within bounding box ?

my java-script code is below

```
(function(global) {

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('maincanvas');       
var yourNameObjs = []; 
var goodtop =358, goodleft=250, boundingObject;

var boundingObject = new fabric.Rect({
                left: 100,
                top: 90,
                width: 200,
                height: 250,
                opacity: 4,
                selectable:false,             
                fill: 'red',
            });
canvas.add(boundingObject); 

addText = function(){
            var nametoprint = $("#nametoprint").val();          

            canvas.remove(yourNameObjs);                

            yourNameObjs = new fabric.Text(nametoprint, { 
                left: 150, //Take the block's position
                opacity: 9,
                top: 150, 
                fontFamily: 'Delicious_500', 

                }
            );
            canvas.add(yourNameObjs);

            canvas.on("object:moving", function(){
                var obj = yourNameObjs;
                var bounds = boundingObject;
                obj.setCoords();
                if(!obj.isContainedWithinObject(bounds)){
                    obj.setTop(goodtop);
                    obj.setLeft(goodleft);                  
                } else {
                    goodtop = obj.top;
                    goodleft = obj.left;
                }  
            });

            canvas.on("object:scaling", function(){
                var obj = yourNameObjs;
                var bounds = boundingObject;
                obj.setCoords();
                if(!obj.isContainedWithinObject(bounds)){
                    obj.setTop(goodtop);
                    obj.setLeft(goodleft);                  
                } else {
                    goodtop = obj.top;
                    goodleft = obj.left;
                }  
            });

            canvas.renderAll();             
        };

    })();
```

html code is below

```
<input type="text" name="nametoprint" id="nametoprint" value="alex" /> 
<input type= "button" name="addtxt" id="addtxt" onclick="addText()" value="add text"  />

<canvas id="maincanvas"  style="border:1px solid #000;"  width="400" height="450" ></canvas>
```

also i added this in fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/pfgm8myp/

i want only allow to scale text object within the red bound box.moving object is working fine.i also added code for scaling but its not working.

can any one suggest me how to restrict this scaling ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i posted it here with my own logic. http://jsfiddle.net/9xojfmyt/

i added below javascript code

```
(function(global) {

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('maincanvas');       
var yourNameObjs = []; 
var goodtop =358, goodleft=250, boundingObject;

var boundingObject = new fabric.Rect({
                left: 100,
                top: 90,
                width: 200,
                height: 250,
                opacity: 4,
                selectable:false,             
                fill: 'red',
            });
canvas.add(boundingObject); 

addText = function(){
            var nametoprint = $("#nametoprint").val();          

            canvas.remove(yourNameObjs);                

            yourNameObjs = new fabric.Text(nametoprint, { 
                left: 150, //Take the block's position
                opacity: 9,
                top: 150, 
                fontFamily: 'Delicious_500', 

                }
            );
            canvas.add(yourNameObjs);

// canvas moving limit
            canvas.observe("object:moving", function(e){
                var obj = yourNameObjs;
                var bounds = boundingObject;
                var objw = parseInt(parseInt(obj.width) * obj.scaleX);
                var objh = parseInt(parseInt(obj.height) * obj.scaleY);
                //left
                if(obj.left < bounds.left){
                    obj.setLeft(bounds.left);
                }
                //top
                if(obj.top < bounds.top){
                    obj.setTop(bounds.top);
                }
                //right
                if((parseInt(obj.left) + objw) > (parseInt(bounds.left)+parseInt(bounds.width))){
                    obj.setLeft(((parseInt(bounds.left)+parseInt(bounds.width)) - objw));                   
                }
                //bottom
                if((parseInt(obj.top) + objh) > (parseInt(bounds.top)+parseInt(bounds.height))){
                    obj.setTop(((parseInt(bounds.top)+parseInt(bounds.height)) - objh));                    
                }               
            });

            // canvas scaling limit
            canvas.observe("object:scaling", function(e){
                var obj = yourNameObjs;
                var bounds = boundingObject;
                var objw = parseInt(parseInt(obj.width) * obj.scaleX);
                var objh = parseInt(parseInt(obj.height) * obj.scaleY);

                //left
                if(obj.left < bounds.left || (parseInt(obj.left) + objw) > (parseInt(bounds.left)+parseInt(bounds.width))){
                    obj.setLeft(bounds.left);
                    obj.setScaleX((bounds.width/obj.width));
                }
                //top
                if(obj.top < bounds.top || (parseInt(obj.top) + objh) > (parseInt(bounds.top)+parseInt(bounds.height))){
                    obj.setTop(bounds.top);
                    obj.setScaleY((bounds.height/obj.height));
                }              
            });

            canvas.renderAll();             
        };

    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit modification compare to `Albert's` answer. If you want to restrict object within canvas then replace `moving` event with below code.

```
// canvas scaling limit
canvas.observe("object:scaling", function(e){
    var obj = e.target;
    var bounds = {
                    left : 5,  //here it keep 5 px margin from all direction
                    top : 5,
                    width : canvas.width - 10,
                    height : canvas.height - 10
                };
    var objw = parseInt(parseInt(obj.width) * obj.scaleX);
    var objh = parseInt(parseInt(obj.height) * obj.scaleY);

    //left
    if(obj.left < bounds.left || (parseInt(obj.left) + objw) > (parseInt(bounds.left)+parseInt(bounds.width))){
        obj.setLeft(bounds.left);
        obj.setScaleX((bounds.width/obj.width));
    }
    //top
    if(obj.top < bounds.top || (parseInt(obj.top) + objh) > (parseInt(bounds.top)+parseInt(bounds.height))){
        obj.setTop(bounds.top);
        obj.setScaleY((bounds.height/obj.height));
    }              
});
```